# How can I force Heroku to run assets:precompile if Rails isn't autodetected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1 application with an usual file layout.  Heroku detects it as Ruby/Rack rather than Ruby/Rails.  `assets:precompile` isn't run, so pages that require them fail with a javascript error.

What do I need in my file structure to trick Heroku into running the precompile task? Or, can I configure a command to run during slug compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have have a `config/application.rb` in your codebase?  This is what the [Heroku ruby buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) uses to detect that it's Rails 3, so it sounds to me like this could be missing.

Once Heroku detects that it's Rails it'll run the `rake assets:precompile`.

Failing that, you could use a gem such as `heroku_san` to add a post deploy hook of `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: The buildpack told me what I wanted, but now I'm going to have a follow on question to actually get the precompile to run without error.